# How to fix this irregularity

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I have used a boolean tool for slicing the object. After that when I started to bevel the object I notice a triangular shape appearing in my object. Please could someone give me a solution for this. I am a beginner in blender.[image]

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Blender prefers quad-based topology for rendering purposes, but Booleans are notorious for leaving tri's and n-gons. (bad topology) These often need to be fixed manually before the mesh appears correct (especially on curved surfaces or with smooth shading). It's hard to tell without seeing your (edit mode) topology, but I suspect it is triangles or n-gons that are causing your mesh to look strange.

Comment: This looks like some overlapping issue caused by bad topology and/or beveling too strong.